# Export data in a .wls script

Tags: scripting

I am currently facing the problem that the `Export` function does not behave as expected if I execute my code as a .wls script.

I execute my test.wls file in my linux shell via the command

```
wolfram -script test.wls
```

In the .wls file I export some sample data via

```
Export["test.txt",list,"Table"]
```

Even though the data stored in the array `list` is exported, the `"Table"` specification is not considered (the data is exported in the typical MMA curly braces). This is in contrast to the executation of the cell in the notebook environment where everything works as intended. Do I need to consider something else if I export some data in a script file?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When I explicitly copy the output of `list` into the `Export` function then the exported output is correct. I thus tried to use `Evaluate` but no change unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried `wolfram -script test.wls -format Table > "test.txt"` instead where in your "test.wls" you use `list` without the `Export[]`?

Comment: Exactly whast does your ``list` look like in Mathematica and what does the contents of "test.txt" look like?